# How to reference a cell where sheet name is cited as a value from a different workbook?

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks `data.xlsx` (which is a readonly and contains sheets `mainsheet`, `a`, `b,`c`,`d`...) and`result.xlsx` (where I will put all my computations and formula).

`data.xlsx!mainsheet` contains:

```
-------
A | B |
-------
1 | c |
2 | b |
3 | a | 
.
.
.
-------
```

and `results.xlsx` contains

```
-------------------
  | A  |  B |  C  |
-------------------
1 |S1  | S2 | Sum |
2 | 3  |  1 |     |
3 | 2  |  3 |     |
4 | 1  |  2 |     |
```

Values of cell `A1` of sheets `a`, `b`, `c` are 10, 5 and 50 respectively.

**What should be the formula so that:**

Sheet C2 should be the sum of A1 values of sheet a and c

Sheet C3 should be the sum of A1 values of sheet b and a

Sheet C2 should be the sum of A1 values of sheet c and b

So the expected result will be cell C2 = 10+50=60, C3=5+10=15, C4=50+5=55.

Comment: run a vba code and everythng will be done automatically in 1 single click.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vlookup` to get the sheenames which needs to be summed.
Use `indirect` to get the values

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A4,[data.xlsx]mainsheet!$A:$B,2,0)&"!A1")+INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(B4,[data.xlsx]mainsheet!$A:$B,2,0)&"!A1")
```

Comment: it gives me `#REF!`

Comment: Ensure there is no spaces etc in mainsheet  B column. If not use `=VLOOKUP(A4,[data.xlsx]mainsheet!$A:$B,2,0)` to see what you get

Comment: i modified you answer a bit to simplify the range  ! [1]: (http://imgur.com/a/rz1sb)